Non-type class template argument deduction
I declared a template class which takes a size_t template argument. Here is the class (or struct in this case):
typedef unsigned char byte;

template <size_t NumBytes>
struct Field
{
    bool is_set = false;
    std::array<byte, NumBytes> data;

    Field() = default;
    Field(byte &&val, bool is_set = false);
    Field(std::initializer_list<byte> predef);
};

The idea is to use it for file header fields (ELF in this case). I want to be able to define a field in the following way:
const Field EI_MAG = {0x7F, 0x45, 0x4c, 0x46};

And have it automatically deduce the template argument NumBytes, such that, in this case, EI_MAG would be of type const Field<4>. The compiler complains a lot (of course) and I eventually get to the point of defining a template deduction guide. My best (and latest) attempt is the following:
template <class Type, class... Data>
Field(Type, Data...) -> Field<sizeof...(Data)>;

But the compiler still complains with the following error:
error: invalid use of template-name ‘Field’ without an argument list
   53 |     const Field EI_MAG          = {0x7F, 0x45, 0x4c, 0x46};
      |           ^~~~~

So how should I do it? Is it even possible? If not, how does std::array do it?
I've been banging my head for several hours, and I still struggle a bit with how template deduction and template deduction guides work. Any help would be much appreciated.
NOTE: All the code presented is located in a .hpp file , and all struct function definitions are located in the corresponding .cpp file, which is not presented here.

What C++ standard are you using? The compilation error suggests that you are using something pre C++17. What is Type doing in the deduction guide? It'll eat the first argument so that the size becomes 3.

Re: "and all struct function definitions are located in the corresponding .cpp file" - That will probably not work well. Put that in the header file too or else you'll have to explicitly instantiate the template for every possible size. That's a lot of instances.

@TedLyngmo The cpp standard is cpp20. I don't really know what I did, but in a move of desperation I copied what std::array does. And indeed, declaring in the cpp file won't work. Thanks for pointing that out!

std::array  uses the first argument to deduce the type and then adds one to the size: array( T, U... ) -> array<T, 1 + sizeof...(U)>; in the deduction guide. You don't need to deduce the type since it's set to be byte.  It's odd that you got the error you got because your code should compile in C++17 and up although it deduces the size to be 3 instead of 4.

Yeah, I just figured it out, I was declaring my variable in a struct and since it is a default argument, it still needs to know what the expected type is. It can't deduce that on it's own.

Ok, I see. Does the class have any other way to initialize EI_MAG or is it always the same in all instances of that class? If it's always the same, you could make it static inline const Field EI_MAG = {0x7F, 0x45, 0x4c, 0x46};.

Yes, It is always the same. And I did what you said and it works! Didn't know about the inline, so thanks!

This compiles after the deduction guide is fixed.
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>

typedef unsigned char byte;

template <size_t NumBytes>
struct Field {
  bool is_set = false;
  std::array<byte, NumBytes> data;

  Field() = default;
  Field(byte &&val, bool is_set = false);
  Field(std::initializer_list<byte> predef);
};

template <class... Data>
Field(Data...) -> Field<sizeof...(Data)>;

const Field EI_MAG = {0x7F, 0x45, 0x4c, 0x46};

It doesn't need class Type.

Ahh, I see my issue, I was declaring the variable in a struct and setting it to {0x7F, 0x45, 0x4c, 0x46} as a default argument, which means that if it isn't default, it still has to know the size, which means that you still need the template specification in the struct declaration. Hope this explanation helps someone. Thank you!

Notice that this CTAD promises that const Field ko(0x7F, 0x45, 0x4c, 0x46) is a Field<4>, but there are no viable constructors.

If you accept to have extra {..} in your call to initialize, you might use C-array and keep default CTAD:
Field(const byte (&predef)[NumBytes]);

with usage
[[maybe_unused]]const Field EI_MAG = {{0x7F, 0x45, 0x4c, 0x46}};
[[maybe_unused]]const Field EI_MAG1{{0x7F, 0x45, 0x4c, 0x46}};

Demo
